# How to improve geometry by merging these ngon faces?

Tags: modeling

I have a model with a frame and a pattern, made after applying the Boolean modifier. The resulting mesh has unconnected faces. How should I "pull" those faces together into a plane? Merge by distance doesn't work because they are not close enough.[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Enable snapping to vertices:

[image]

And auto-merdge:

[image]

Now you can snap vertex to vertex, and they will be merged